# Form Submissions to multiple Spreadsheets using 'onsubmit'

Tags: google-apps-script, form-submit, google-forms

I have a Gform where I need the submission to go to 1 of 3 spreadsheets based upon a multiple choice answer in the first question. As shown below.

Which Project is this for?

1. Project A
2. Project B
3. Project C

I am constrained to using 1 initial form. I need the submissions to go to completely different spreadsheets, not just different tabs in one spreadsheet. And, I can not use the import range function as it will not allow data to be overridden in the case of a mistake during the original submission without going to the form response page with the other projects submissions and data.

My two current ideas are,

1. Use a 'onsubmit' script to route the submissions based upon their answer to the first question, but I cannot find any other examples on how to do this or where someone has done something similar. The closest I have found is using onsubmit to send specific emails afterwards but nothing on actually changing the destination of the submission.
2. Build the form using script where after they answer the first question (Project A, B, C) it will redirect to another section or seperate form where the submission will be sent to the spreadsheets for each project. For this idea I'm having trouble figuring out how to either get different form sections to submit to seperate spreadsheets or how to get the user to be redirected to another form based upon their answer to the first question.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: A third possibility could be not to use Google Forms.  Instead build your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the first alternative:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var ssObj={'ProjectA':'ssid','ProjectB':'ssid','ProjectC':'ssid'};
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssObj[e.values[1]]);//assuming question one is the answer for which project the response is supposed to go to
  var sh=ss.getSheets()[0];
  sh.appendRow(e.values)';
}
```

Okay so I see that you need some explanation.

1. First you have to setup an onFormSubit() trigger. You can do that from `Edit/Current Project Triggers menu`.  When this function is triggered by the submission of a form then e.values will be the array of all  answers from  that form.

You can also do that with code:

```
function createOnFormSubmitTrigger() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit').forSpreadsheet(ss.getId()).onFormSubmit().create();
}
```

2. `ssObbj` is a javascript object that you create based upon the information in question one's answer.  `var ssObj={'The answer for for project A':'the spreadsheet id for project A','the answer for project B':'the spreadsheet id for project b','the answer for project C':'the spreadsheet id for answer C'};`

Some references to read.

[onFormSubmit Object for spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

[onFormSubmit Object for form](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_1)

[SpreadsheetApp.openById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String))

[Sheet.appendRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object))

Comment: Thanks, this definitely helps and I understand this somewhat but if you have a min I have 2 quick questions.  Where does the ss0bj come from? And secondly for the [e.values[1]]);  I get an "cannot read properly "values"" error code. Is this something I need to define?

Comment: I think I might of fixed the issue I just asked about by adding and linking an on submit trigger. But I now get a "cannot find function openByID in object SpreadsheetApp"?  Any suggestions? Do I need to like or allow access to the three other spreadsheets I will be using for output?

Comment: You can learn about JavaScript Objects [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) And you can't run a function like this from the script editor.  It has to be provided an [onFormSubmit Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit).  Be careful with that when you read about because the event object for a form is different than the one for the linked spreadsheet.

Comment: [SpreadsheetApp.openById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String))